# How to load script using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementByID` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

I load the file using jquery.load(). In my load_to.html I am targeting the element with id as

```
$('#users').change(function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

this element is present in load_from.html. I couldn't able to target this. But when I inspect the page I can able to see this element.

I loaded the page like this

```
$('#mydiv').load('/user/1/edit form');
```

How to target the element?

Comment: @roXon what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `on` in it's delegate signature:

```
$('#mydiv').on('change', '#users', function() {
  alert('hello');
});
```

[Read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: interesting how no-one is upvoting Questioners. People who really need votes. :) Happy New Year bro! +1

Comment: @roXon, it could be a good question if it wasn't so commonly asked, it's even in [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F) btw, they show the way with the binding in the load function(mcpDESIGNS) AND my way...

Answer (score 1):

Try to set up your events in the callback from `.load` to make sure they are created once the elements enter the DOM.

```
$('#mydiv').load('/user/1/edit form', function () {

    //Callback
    //set up events here (once it is finished loading)

    $('#users').change(function() {
        alert('hello');
    });
});
```

Comment: again no no and no, it's not wrong but it's not the way somsone should write jQ. that's why we have the (ex .live() ) `.on()` method. A load callback should not carry future events, at least not for a legible code. inside a load c.b. you expect to see some features that will happen after a success response, not to see events delegation.

Comment: @roXon, Actually I see nothing wrong with this approach, I'm upvoting this as it's perfectly valid! +1

Comment: @gdoron don't push me to upvote this answer, cause **yes**, it's perfectly correct, just trying to share my thoughts and a way to write logic code.

Comment: @roXon Well at the same time using delegated stuff works great, I like how wrapped together this is. Obviously the page being loaded should have it's own events / JS set up. I just personally think it can be confusing to have delegated events only to do with a `load`'d page within the parent.